# Does MobileFirst 7.1 Cordova App support Application Authenticity

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

We are building a hybrid mobile app with IBM MobileFirst platform 7.1. The app is created as MFP Cordova app:

`$ mfp cordova create someApp --platform ios`

We are trying to figure out whether MFP App Authenticity feature is supported when in MFP Cordova app. According to this link:

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_cordova_vs_hybrid.html?lang=en

The "Verification of the integrity of web resources by using a checksum each time the app starts running. ( in the application descriptor)" is not supported for Cordova app. Does this imply the App Authenticity is not supported as well? From the same link, it mentioned that "MobileFirst Security Framework" is supported Cordova. So, please clarify.

Another associated question.  On the same comparison page above, it specifies that "Specification of app target category (B2E or B2C) for addressable device license tracking. ( in application descriptor)" is not supported for Cordova based app. Does this mean that Cordova based app can NOT be used if the MFP server is using Token Licensing as specified below:

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_setting_license_app_type.html?lang=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`testWebResourcesChecksum` is not the same as Application Authenticity.

Application Authenticity is supported, however note that there is an open issue that causes Extended Authenticity to fail: PI58292 EXTENDED AUTHENTICITY FOR CORDOVA-BASED HYBRID APP FAILS - this is being addressed.

I am not sure about the license tracking feature - checking.
Update: license tracking is supported as well.